# The onclick events are not firing and the dropdown code is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

See code at https://jsfiddle.net/Spleendrivel/x718xd87/

I also found that when I replaced the uncompressed library links with the compressed version the navbar menu is no longer visible at all.

Would like to have this working so the dropdown menu items actually list the items under each and the onclick events function as expected.

One last question, I had everything working at one point and then found that it no longer worked on my phone so I started debugging only to end up with a non-functioning menu!

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="Width=device-Width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Arizona - Yavapai Area of NA</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                margin: 0;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                background: url(images/SandyBackground.jpg) repeat
            }

            @media screen and (max-width: 2400px) {
                body {
                    font-size: 2vw;
                    color: black;
                }
            }

            @media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
                body {
                    font-size: 1.8vw;
                    color: black;
                }
            }

            .hidden {
                display:none;
            }

            svg text {
               font-family: FontAwesome;
            }

            .icon::before {
                display: inline-block;
                margin-right: .5em;
                font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
                font-size: inherit;
                text-rendering: auto;
                -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
                -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
                transform: translate(0, 0);
            }

            td {
                padding:0 5px 0 5px;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
  <body>
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <img src="images/HeaderImage.jpg" class="img-responsive">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
            <H4><Strong>Need Help?</Strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;928-458-7488</H4>
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
         <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
               <li class="menu-item dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" onclick="CloseAll();">Meetings</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                     <li class="menu-item "><a href="#" onclick="toggleAllMeetings();" class="dropdown-item">All Meetings w/Legend</a></li>
                     <li class="menu-item "><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="toggleMonMeetings();">Monday</a></li>
                     <li class="menu-item "><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="toggleTueMeetings();">Tuesday</a></li>
                     <li class="menu-item "><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="toggleWedMeetings();">Wednesday</a></li>
                     <li class="menu-item "><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="toggleThuMeetings();">Thursday</a></li>
                     <li class="menu-item "><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="toggleFriMeetings();">Friday</a></li>
                     <li class="menu-item "><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="toggleSatMeetings();">Saturday</a></li>
                     <li class="menu-item "><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="toggleSunMeetings();">Sunday</a></li>
                     <li class="menu-item ">
                        <div class="dropdown-divider">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
                     </li>
                     <li class="menu-item "><a class="dropdown-item" target="_blank" onclick="CloseAll();" href="Files/2018-04-17-Spring-Meeting-List.pdf">Print List</a></li>
                     <li class="menu-item ">
                        <div class="dropdown-divider">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
                     </li>
                     <li class="menu-item "><a class="dropdown-item" onclick="toggleCommitteeMeetings();" href="#">Committee Meetings</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
               <li class="menu-item "><a href="#" onclick="toggleLocalEvents();" class="nav_link">EVENTS</a></li>
               <li class="menu-item dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" onclick="CloseAll();">Documents</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                     <li class="menu-item "><a target="_blank" href="Files/2017-11-06_YASC_Group_Order_Form.pdf" class="dropdown-item">Group Order Form</a></li>
                     <li class="menu-item "><a target="_blank" href="Files/Treasurer-Group-Report-Form.pdf" class="dropdown-item">Group Treasurer's Form</a></li>
                     <li class="menu-item "><a target="_blank" href="Files/Yavapai_Area_Service_Guidelines_Revised_December_2016.pdf" class="dropdown-item">Yavapai Area Service Guidelines</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
               <li class="menu-item dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" onclick="CloseAll();">Other Links</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="menu-item "><A target="_blank" href="http://www.arizona-na.org/" class="dropdown-item">Arizona Region</a></li>
                            <li class="menu-item "><A target="_blank" href="http://www.vvana.info/" class="dropdown-item">Verde Valley Area</a></li>
                            <li class="menu-item "><A target="_blank" href="http://na.org/" class="dropdown-item">World Services</a></li>
                     </ul>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JQuery code -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <!-- Latest compiled and minified BootStrap Code -->
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script>
            function toggleAllMeetings() {
             if (AllMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              AllMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';
             else
              AllMeetingsContent.style.display = 'block';

             if (MonMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              MonMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (TueMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              TueMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (WedMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              WedMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (ThuMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              ThuMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (FriMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              FriMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (SatMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              SatMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (SunMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              SunMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (LocalEventsContent.style.display == 'block')
              LocalEventsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (CommitteeMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              CommitteeMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';
            }

            function toggleMonMeetings() {
             if (MonMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              MonMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';
             else
              MonMeetingsContent.style.display = 'block';

             if (TueMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              TueMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (WedMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              WedMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (ThuMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              ThuMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (FriMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              FriMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (SatMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              SatMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (SunMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              SunMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (AllMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              AllMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (LocalEventsContent.style.display == 'block')
              LocalEventsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (CommitteeMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              CommitteeMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';
            }

            function toggleTueMeetings() {
             if (TueMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              TueMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';
             else
              TueMeetingsContent.style.display = 'block';

             if (MonMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              MonMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (WedMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              WedMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (ThuMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              ThuMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (FriMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              FriMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (SatMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              SatMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (SunMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              SunMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (AllMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              AllMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (LocalEventsContent.style.display == 'block')
              LocalEventsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (CommitteeMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              CommitteeMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';
            }

            function toggleWedMeetings() {
             if (WedMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              WedMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';
             else
              WedMeetingsContent.style.display = 'block';

             if (MonMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              MonMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (TueMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              TueMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (ThuMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              ThuMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (FriMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              FriMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (SatMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              SatMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (SunMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              SunMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (AllMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              AllMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (LocalEventsContent.style.display == 'block')
              LocalEventsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (CommitteeMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              CommitteeMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';
            }

            function toggleThuMeetings() {
             if (ThuMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              ThuMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';
             else
              ThuMeetingsContent.style.display = 'block';

             if (MonMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              MonMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (TueMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              TueMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (WedMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              WedMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (FriMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              FriMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (SatMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              SatMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (SunMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              SunMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (AllMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              AllMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (LocalEventsContent.style.display == 'block')
              LocalEventsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (CommitteeMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              CommitteeMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';
            }

            function toggleFriMeetings() {
             if (FriMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              FriMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';
             else
              FriMeetingsContent.style.display = 'block';

             if (MonMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              MonMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (TueMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              TueMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (WedMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              WedMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (ThuMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              ThuMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (SatMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              SatMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (SunMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              SunMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (AllMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              AllMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (LocalEventsContent.style.display == 'block')
              LocalEventsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (CommitteeMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              CommitteeMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';
            }

            function toggleSatMeetings() {
             if (SatMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              SatMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';
             else
              SatMeetingsContent.style.display = 'block';

             if (MonMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              MonMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (TueMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              TueMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (WedMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              WedMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (ThuMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              ThuMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (FriMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              FriMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (SunMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              SunMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (AllMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              AllMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (LocalEventsContent.style.display == 'block')
              LocalEventsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (CommitteeMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              CommitteeMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';
            }

            function toggleSunMeetings() {
             if (SunMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              SunMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';
             else
              SunMeetingsContent.style.display = 'block';

             if (MonMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              MonMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (TueMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              TueMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (WedMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              WedMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (ThuMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              ThuMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (FriMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              FriMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (SatMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              SatMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (AllMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              AllMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (LocalEventsContent.style.display == 'block')
              LocalEventsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (CommitteeMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              CommitteeMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';
            }

            function toggleLocalEvents() {
             if (LocalEventsContent.style.display == 'block')
              LocalEventsContent.style.display = 'none';
             else
              LocalEventsContent.style.display = 'block';

             if (MonMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              MonMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (TueMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              TueMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (WedMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              WedMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (ThuMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              ThuMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (FriMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              FriMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (SatMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              SatMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (SunMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              SunMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (AllMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              AllMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (AllMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              AllMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (CommitteeMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              CommitteeMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';
            }

            function toggleCommitteeMeetings() {
             if (CommitteeMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              CommitteeMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';
             else
              CommitteeMeetingsContent.style.display = 'block';

             if (MonMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              MonMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (TueMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              TueMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (WedMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              WedMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (ThuMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              ThuMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (FriMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              FriMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (SatMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              SatMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (SunMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              SunMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (AllMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              AllMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (LocalEventsContent.style.display == 'block')
              LocalEventsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (AllMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              AllMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';
            }

            function CloseAll() {
             if (CommitteeMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              CommitteeMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (MonMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              MonMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (TueMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              TueMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (WedMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              WedMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (ThuMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              ThuMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (FriMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              FriMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (SatMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              SatMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (SunMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              SunMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (AllMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              AllMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (LocalEventsContent.style.display == 'block')
              LocalEventsContent.style.display = 'none';
            }

        < /script>
    </body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle selects and inputs its adding a listener to it, for example:

```
$('select').on('change', function(e) {
console.log(this.value); // Here you can do whatever you want
})
```

Comment: Please delete this question!